# rails scss assets being imported twice

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, sprockets

I'm working on a Rails app that I didn't write, and I realised that the compiled stylesheet contains the Bootstrap CSS twice. These two screenshots are from the same file, the compiled /assets/application-2d2c43940p[...].css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *'
 *= require normalize
 *= require jquery.tagit
 *= require tagit.ui-zendesk
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.5 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
/*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
/* line 9, /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@gradready/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_normalize.scss */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

and

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *'






 */
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.5 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
/*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
/* line 9, /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@gradready/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_normalize.scss */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Note that the require statements are blanked out in the second copy. However if I search for Bootstrap, it only appears once, in the application.scss file, pictured below. Why could this be happening?

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *'
 *= require normalize
 *= require jquery.tagit
 *= require tagit.ui-zendesk
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
@import 'chosen/chosen.min';
@import "video-js";
@import "videojs-resolution-selector/video-quality-selector";
@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';
@import 'jquery.fileupload';
@import 'jquery.fileupload-ui';

// COLORS
$grGreen: #009348;
```

Also, my application .scss, i.e. code that I myself have written, only appears once. It only seems to be some libraries that are being imported twice.

Comment: If you have `*= require_tree .` and your predecessor was a lazy oaf and just downloaded all the libraries into app/assets they will be added twice...

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't seem to be in app/assets, or vendor/assets, or lib/assets. It's very strange.